# Уживутся ли на одном виртуальном сервере RoR и Apache+PHP+MySQL?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, ruby-on-rails, php7

Имеется виртуальный сервер у Скэйлвэя (4 x86 64bit Cores, 4GB Memory, 100GB SSD Disk), где на Ubuntu 14.04 установлена связка Apache+PHP+MySQL, на которой работают с десяток сайтов общей посещаемостью около 1000 хостов в сутки (движки MaxSite CMS и WordPress).

Недавно начал изучать Ruby on Rails и возникла необходимость перехода от локальной машины к серверу, чтобы разместить кое-что онлайн. Посещаемость, естественно, будет практически нулевая - я и еще несколько человек.

Однако, не уверен, что можно параллельно ставить RoR и Apache+PHP+MySQL как с точки зрения производительности, так и с точки зрения безопасности.

Можно ли все это установить на одном виртуальном сервере, или лучше под RoR взять новый?

Comment: Очень много переменных. Формально ответ "да, их можно заставить жить вместе без проблем", но встают вопросы нагруженности сервера, общих для приложений ресурсов (MySQL-сервер?), доверия всем сторонам по части безопасности и, наконец, вашего опыта администрирования серверов. В итоге полный ответ выйдет... немного километровым.

Comment: Я уже понял, что лучше отдельный сервер под RoR, поскольку серьезными скилами в области администрирования не обладаю.

Answer (score 1):

Под другой язык, в любом случае будет лучше взять другой виртуальный сервер, но это условное "лучше", не значить что нельзя на одном виртуальном сервере держать сразу несколько языков. Если ваш сервер справляется с данной нагрузкой, то от нового модуля в виде интерпретатора языка, и его фреймворка, проблем не будет, тем более что на этой технологии вы реализуете всего один сайт, и посещаемости у него не будет. Но в любом случае, нам тяжело оценивать ситуацию так, лучше добавьте **данные об загрузке виртуального сервера**, в самый пиковый период, по вашему мнению

P.S за свою практику, мне приходилось на одном сервере совмещать 3 языка, PHP, JS(Node), и C++.